# Función JavaScript recibe parámetro pero Ajax no se ejecuta y no muestra ningún error

Tags: php, javascript, ajax

Estoy intentando hacer un UPDATE en Mysqli a través de PDO dándole a un botón en HTML creado con PHP. Para ello, el botón activa una función de JavaScript que envía el parámetro que necesito al archivo PHP que se encarga de realizar esto. Sé que el archivo PHP funciona correctamente porque he probado meterle el ID desde el html con un formulario y sin pasar por JS y se ejecuta sin problema y me cambia el registro en la base de datos. También sé que la función es llamada correctamente ya que al hacer click sobre el elemento puedo ver en Network que el id que recibe es el correcto y además me saca los alert y console.logs que le incluyo dentro de la función y antes de llamar a Ajax. Con un alert también he comprobado que el parámetro entra bien. Pero por algún motivo, mi Ajax nunca se ejecuta. He comprobado mil veces el nombre y el directorio del archivo php y son correctos. Además, el Ajax está copiado de otro que sí que funciona cambiandole simplemente la url a la que dirige y la data que tiene que mandar.

Mi main.js:

```
function marcarLeido(isbn) {


  var url = 'marcarleido.php';
  $.ajax({
    url: url,
    method: "POST",
    data: {
      isbn

    },
    success: function (response) {
      console.log("JS ok");
      alert('boton click');
    }
  });
  }
```

Por si acaso, mi marcarleido.php:

```
<?php
session_start();
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
</head>
<?php
    if (isset($_POST['isbn'])) {
        include("funcionesPDO.php");

        $isbn = $_POST['isbn'];

        $conex = conectar();

        $stmt = $conex->prepare("UPDATE books SET leido = 1 WHERE isbn = :id AND id_usuario = :par");
        $stmt->bindValue(':par', $_SESSION['usuario_id']);
        $stmt->bindValue(':id', $isbn);
        $stmt->execute();
        

        desconectar($conex);

    }
?>
</p>
<!-- Scripts-->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js" ></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.100.2/js/materialize.min.js" ></script>
  <script src="_javascript/main.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Y por si acaso también, el html index.php (aunque parece que llama correctamente)

```
<?php
                        include("funcionesPDO.php");
                        $conex = conectar();

                        $stmt = $conex->prepare("SELECT * FROM books WHERE leido = 0 AND id_usuario = :is");
                        $stmt->bindValue(':is', $_SESSION['usuario_id']);
                        $stmt->execute();
                        $libros = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);


                        foreach($libros as $libro){
                         echo  "<div class='column'>";
                          echo "<div class='card card-equal-height'>";
                            echo "<div class='card-image form_photo'>";
                              echo "<figure class='image is-4by3'>";
                                echo "<img src='".$libro['imagen']."'>";
                              echo "</figure>";
                            echo "</div>";
                            echo "<div class='card-content'>";
                              echo "<p class='title is-5 has-text-centered'>". $libro['titulo'] ."</p>";
                                echo "<p class='subtitle is-6 has-text-centered'>". $libro['autor']."</p>";
                            echo "</div>";
                            echo "<div class='card-footer level-item'>";
                                      echo "<a href='' onclick='marcarLeido(".$libro['isbn'].")'><p class='card-footer-item'>";
                                      echo "<i class='fas fa-bookmark'></i>";
                                       echo "<span>&nbsp;Leído</a></span></p></a>";
                                      echo "<a href=''><p class='card-footer-item'>";
                                      echo "<i class='fas fa-paper-plane'></i>";
                                        echo "<span>&nbsp; Enviar</a></span></p>";
                                   echo  "</div></div></div>";
                        }
                        desconectar($conex);
                        ?>
```

Comment: Es el mismo problema de tu otra pregunta y sigo pensando que la ruta no es correcta. ¿Qué aparece en la barra de direcciones cuando listas los libros? Debe ser algo como `http://localhost/proyecto/listado.php`

Comment: Ya ajusté la respuesta, con todos los detalles necesarios para que la entiendas. En caso de que tu ruta sea correcta, tu tratamiento de de la solicitud tiene fallos. Coincido con @Triby en que debes revisar la ruta.

Answer (score 0):

Tu problema está en el envío de los datos. Tu variable data no está siendo configurada correctamente.
Tienes:

```
data: {
      isbn

    },
```

Y, allí no hay presente una clave isbn que pueda ser recogida en `$_POST` por el archivo que procesa la petición.
Cambia data de esta manera (no necesitas pasarla con formato Json para este caso)

```
url='marcarleido.php';
var jqxhr = $.ajax({ url: url, type: 'POST', 'data': 'isbn='+isbn } )
.done(function(retornotxt) { 
  // hacer lo que necesites con el valor devuelto en retornotxt
});
```

Eso asegura que la superglobal $_POST reciba una clave isbn con el valor asociado.

Adicionalmente, tu "marcarleido.php" está escrito para devolver una página completa no para devolver un bloque de texto que será tratado al manejar la respuesta haciendo algunos cambios dentro de la página que hace la solicitud. Debes reescribirlo siguiendo las indicaciones que te planteo en la explicación:

### Explicaciones adicionales

**Razón de ser del uso de Ajax**
Se trata de hacer un intercambio "ligero" de datos con el servidor para actualizar información en el mismo y/o actualizar partes de la página activa en el cliente **sin necesidad de recargarla completamente**.
Esto tiene dos implicaciones: a. se deben preparar y formatear los datos a enviar, antes de hacer la solicitud (en el cliente), de modo que b. puedan ser recogidos e interpretados del otro lado (servidor)

**Preparación del llamado**
No me voy a extender en todos los detalles. Sólo trato los fundamentales:
El llamado usando [jquery](/questions/tagged/jquery) tiene típicamente 3 parámetros que se pueden pasar con nombre `url` la dirección del recurso que atenderá la solicitud (en tu caso **'marcarleido.php'**. Es posible que necesite algún ajuste para que la ruta apunte realmente al recurso; pero con lo que publicas no puedo saberlo.) `type` el tipo o método usado para en llamado (en este caso será **'post'**) y `data` que se llena con los datos a enviar al servidor.
En el llamado que se puso arriba se ilustra como asignar el contenido de data de modo que el isbn que quieres enviar pase a la superglobal $_POST de modo que tu php lo recoja leyendo $_POST['isbn']. En la forma en que lo pasabas nunca va a ser leído así.

**Tratamiento de la solicitud**
Se trata de un script php que lee los datos enviados desde el cliente. Hace algo con ellos y prepara una respuesta.
En tu caso, el código php inicial, para tratar la solicitud parece correcto. Pero, le hace falta producir y enviar una respuesta. Y sobran tanto el bloque html inicial como el final, porque no estás tratando de servir una nueva página.
Debes reducirte a

```
<?php
    session_start();
    // Supongo que en algún lado haces algo con la sesión y controlas lo necesario
    // Se borra todo el html que había aquí
    if (isset($_POST['isbn'])) {
        include("funcionesPDO.php");
        $isbn = $_POST['isbn'];
        $conex = conectar();
        $stmt = $conex->prepare("UPDATE books SET leido = 1 WHERE isbn = :id AND id_usuario = :par");
        $stmt->bindValue(':par', $_SESSION['usuario_id']);
        $stmt->bindValue(':id', $isbn);
        $stmt->execute();
        desconectar($conex);
        // ENVIAS UNA RESPUESTA
        echo 'Se actualizó el registro';
    }else{
        // REPORTAS NO HAY DATOS
        echo 'No se recibieron los datos esperados';
    }
    // Finalizas el script enviando la respuesta al cliente
    exit();
?>
// EL resto de tu código sobra
```

**Tratamiento de la respuesta del servidor**
El llamado ajax **es asíncrono** Esto quiere decir que se debe esperar por una respuesta que puede o no llegar y las líneas javascript posteriores a la que hace el llamado se ejecutan antes de que el llamado devuelva algo.
En consecuencia se deben usar unos callbacks (retrollamados o métodos de retorno) que son invocados cuando la solicitud se completa o cuando se declara fallida. Típicamente son success(), done(), fail(), en tu código se usa success(). Pero, yo siempre uso .done() veamos su implementación:

```
var jqxhr = $.ajax({ url: 'marcarleido.php', type: 'POST', 'data': 'isbn='+isbn } )
.done(function(retornotxt) { 
    // le puse retornotxt a la variable para que sea explícito que es
    // un bloque de texto (así sea json **es texto**) que debe
    // interpretarse (aunque en este caso no hace falta porque
    // se mostrará lo devuelto por el servidor)
    console.log(retornotxt);
    alert(retornotxt);
})
.fail(function() {
    // Notificas el fallo, para que pase algo y se note
    var msj='Se produjo un fallo en la solicitud';
    console.log(msj);
    alert(msj);
});

// nota: var jqxhr no es necesario (es un uso personal 
// por si adelante quiero hacer algo más con el objeto) puede quitarse.
```

Comment: pues nada, no ha funcionado, sigue sin hacer nada :(

Comment: ya edito puede ser que necesites usar un ligero cambio

Comment: lo siento, pero no termino de entender esa variable que creas para darle el valor del ajax ni exactamente qué indica la parte de ".done: etc." Soy muy noob, sorry

Comment: Hay otros detalles adicionales que fallan en tu php para tratar la solicitud. Debes finalizar el script php con exit(). Pensé que lo haces en desconectar($conex); y noto que no lo haces. De modo que no te opera como esperas. **Voy a agregar una explicación algo larga para que se entienda el asunto**

Answer (score 0):

Lo que puedes hacer es una un FormData para mandar tus parámetros por ajax.

```
function marcarLeido(isbn) {
  const datos = new FormData();
  datos.append('isbn', isbn)

  var url = 'marcarleido.php';
  $.ajax({
    url: url,
    method: "POST",
    data: datos,
    success: function (response) {
      console.log("JS ok");
      alert('boton click');
    }
  });
}
```

De esta forma puedes enviarlo al back y lo podra recibir sin problemas